# Autodoc single module attribute in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, docutils

Say I have documented a variable in a Python module, like so:

```
some_random_name = 'whatever'
"""The random whatever variable"""
```

Can I include autodocs for that single variable in my .rst file, *without* also dragging in the module `__doc__` string and generating documentation output for that too?

I have tried

```
.. automodule: themodule
   :members: some_random_name
```

but that both drags in the `__doc__` string and does not show autodocs for `some_random_name`.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce the problem with documenting the module attribute. It works for me. Do you by any chance have an `__all__` variable in your module whose value does not include `some_random_name`? [Sphinx considers  `__all__`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-automodule) when looking for members.

The module docstring can be removed by intercepting the [`autodoc-process-docstring`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-docstring) event. Here is a demonstration (add the code to **conf.py**):

```
import inspect

def remove_mod_docstring(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    """Erase module docstring in-place"""  
    if inspect.ismodule(obj):
        for i in xrange(len(lines)):
            lines[i] = ''

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', remove_mod_docstring)
```

Comment: I solved this another way (complete workaround, not related to this problem), but will check your solution later.